# Element Plus UI: No open to new tab for menu item

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

I have created a horizontal menu for Element Plus UI on Vue. When I right click on a menu item, I do not have the option to open it in a new tab.

[image: No open to a new tab option]

But when on the element plus documentation. When I right click on a menu item I have that option:

[image: Right Click menu option]

How do I achieve that functionality since I can't find any references on that on the documentation?

**Menu Code:**

```
<template>
  <el-menu
    class="sideMenu"
    :collapse="isCollapse"
    active-text-color="#409EFF"
    :default-active="activeLink"
    text-color="#909399"
    background-color="#FFFFFF"
    :router="true"
  >
    <el-menu-item index="/menu1">
      <el-icon><DocumentChecked /></el-icon>
      <span>Menu 1</span>
    </el-menu-item>

    <el-menu-item index="/menu2">
      <el-icon><DocumentChecked /></el-icon>
      <span>Menu 2</span>
    </el-menu-item>
  </el-menu>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Element Plus [documentation](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/menu.html#menu-item-attributes) el-menu-item
has an attribute of **route**: which is type Obj. So, the el-menu-item class would be like:

```
<el-menu-item index="/menu1" route= VUE-ROUTER-OBJ>
```

Or You can use the menu attribute which activates routing from the index value of menu-items:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<el-menu
    :default-active="activeIndex"
    class="el-menu-demo"
    mode="horizontal"
    @select="handleSelect"
    router= true 
  >
<!-- router is the key attribute-->


<el-menu-item index="/" route="/"> Home </el-menu-item>

<el-menu-item index="PATH OF VUE ROUTER"> LINK NAME </el-menu-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use `el-link` inside the menu items to make it fully work with ctrl + click and also manually right click and select the "open in new tab" option:

```
<el-menu mode="horizontal" menu-trigger="click" ref="menuRef" >
    <el-menu-item>
      <el-link :underline="false" class="nav-brand" :href="/home">
        Home</el-link>
    </el-menu-item>
</el-menu>
```

Also there is [a issue known](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/13293) when you use `menu-trigger="click"` mode. The submenus only are closed when user click on the submenu title, not when use click away outside the menu!  To fix that, you can use  `import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core'` like this:

```
<template>
  <el-menu mode="horizontal" menu-trigger="click" ref="menuRef">
    <el-sub-menu :index="'customMenuIndex'">
      <template #title>
        <span>Title</span>
      </template>
      <el-menu-item>
        <el-link :underline="false" :href="'/subpage'">SubMenu</el-link>
      </el-menu-item>
    </el-sub-menu>
  </el-menu>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core'

const menuRef = ref(null)

onClickOutside(menuRef, (event) => {
  menuRef.value.close('customMenuIndex')
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add anchor tag inside `el-menu-item`.

```
 <el-menu-item index="4">
     <a href="https://www.ele.me" target="_blank">
        <el-icon><DocumentChecked /></el-icon>
        <span>Menu 1</span>
    </a>
</el-menu-item>

<el-menu-item index="4"><a href="https://www.ele.me" target="_blank">Simple Link</a></el-menu-item>
```

Comment: it turns the whole thing into a link. When I click it it will break vue routers functionality